# Charmcrypto Installation: ImportError during make

Tags: python-2.7, cryptography, charm-crypto

```
Setup build/staging directories
set -x
set +x
Building the Charm Framework
/usr/bin/python3 setup.py build  
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.42.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dslab/Downloads/Charm-Crypto-0.43/distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
    raise ImportError
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    use_setuptools() #bootstrap installs Distribute if not installed
  File "/home/dslab/Downloads/Charm-Crypto-0.43/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
    return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/dslab/Downloads/Charm-Crypto-0.43/distribute_setup.py", line 124, in _do_download
    to_dir, download_delay)
  File "/home/dslab/Downloads/Charm-Crypto-0.43/distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
    src = urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 472, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 582, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 510, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
Makefile:27: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I was trying to install Charm-crypto python 3 version on Ubuntu 16.04. 
I have installed all specified dependencies, however, the process fails with the following error during make.

And hence I am not able to proceed further. Please help in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was installing it on a Ubuntu 18.4 LTS, but the solution for me was to follow [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ace/install-charm.html) website.

This might help aswell:

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libboost-all-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libfreetype6-dev libpng-dev
```

And you may want to check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233351/problem-with-installing-charm-crypto-for-python3/54304895#54304895) post.