# Problem with installing Charm-Crypto for Python3

Tags: python, cryptography, exit-code, gcc-warning, charm-crypto

Hello fellow Programmers, 
currently I am trying to install [Charm-Crypto 0.43](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/install_source.html) on my Ubuntu. Unfortunately nothing seems to work. I tried the linked manual install, as well as `pip install charm-crypto`

I always get this Error log:

```
[...]
running build_ext
    building 'charm.core.math.pairing' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/charm
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/charm/core
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/charm/core/math
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/charm/core/math/pairing
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/charm/core/utilities
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/charm/core/benchmark
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DBENCHMARK_ENABLED=1 -Icharm/core/utilities/ -Icharm/core/benchmark/ -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/debbi/Documents/env/01_chainmed/include/python3.6m -c charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.o
    In file included from charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.c:30:0:
    charm/core/math/pairing/pairingmodule.h:38:10: fatal error: pbc/pbc.h: No such file or directory
     #include <pbc/pbc.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/debbi/Documents/env/01_chainmed/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-wfcawqbr/charm-crypto/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-pfeoo7we/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/debbi/Documents/env/01_chainmed/include/site/python3.6/charm-crypto" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-wfcawqbr/charm-crypto/
```

I tried every suggested install of python-dev and libssl etc. I could find by googling ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26053982/setup-script-exited-with-error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27130286/error-command-x86-64-linux-gnu-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-in-virtualenv), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094718/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-while-installing-eventlet) just to name a view). I also tried installing it using python2.7 and 3.6 Unfortunately nothing worked for me.

Maybe anyone knows this Problem?

Thank You for your time in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this Website: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ace/install-charm.html
Just follow the Instructions, but for me I had to manually check out the Charm-0.50 dev branch and then install this version.